# getElementsByClassName and quote issue

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to make a php variable with some js inside for inserting this with an echo

```
$imagerollover = ' onmouseover="document.getElementsByClassName(".'.trim($item->classe).' a img").src=\'' . JURI::base(true) . '/' . $menu_image_hover . '\'"
```

and then

```
echo '<li '.$imagerollover.'.......
```

I have a annoying issue :

- the double-quote make some bad output in my html because js stop on double-quote...
- I have try many conbinaison but I don't find

Thanks for your help on this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use ""(double quotes) for outermost wrapping and ''(single quotes) for inside wrapping..

Remove "." for document.getElementsByClassName(**`".'`**.trim($item->classe), remove this.

For  `document.getElementsByClassName(className)` , you don't need to give dot specifier ..

Comment: It seems to be good but I make a lot of more mistakes because I want to select the img tag and this js function just select nodes... I have to work a lot more on this .thks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$imagerollover = ' onmouseover="document.getElementsByClassName(\''.trim($item->classe).' a img\'); src="' . JURI::base(true) .  $menu_image_hover . '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

And at the end it works as wanted with this :

```
onmouseover="jQuery(\'.'.trim($item->classe).' a img\').attr(\'src\',\'' . JURI::base(true) . '/' . $menu_image_hover . '\')"
```